# What is the syntax error of below sql code?

Tags: mysql, sql

the following is my code

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `trealcap_crm`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `moovpay_update_status`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`trealcap_admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `moovpay_update_status`()
BEGIN
DECLARE id INT;
DECLARE current INT ;
DECLARE totalCount INT ;
DECLARE fundmoney2 DECIMAL;
SET current = 0;
IF (ROW_COUNT() > 0)

BEGIN
END
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

but after i execute , it give me the error, the error is there

IF (ROW_COUNT() > 0)
    BEGIN
    END$$

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
END' at line 9

what wrongs with that begin in mysql?

Comment: Please read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` statement in MySQL has the syntax:

```
    IF (ROW_COUNT() > 0) THEN
        . . .
    END IF;
```

You still need the

```
END$$
```

for the procedure `BEGIN`/`END` block.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF
END' at line 9